# correct syntax for git remote clone

Tags: git

How can I clone a git repository remotely to a Rails application directory on the same server as the repository?

If I do the following, the cloned repository ends up on my local/Windows machine, which is not what I want:

```
git clone -q username@server.com:/users/home/jdquirke/git/deq.git \
    /users/home/username/rails_apps/deq/releases/20130305205259
```

If I do the following instead,

```
git clone -q username@server.com:/users/home/jdquirke/git/deq.git \
    username@server.com:/users/home/username/rails_apps/deq/releases/20130305205259
```

I get

> fatal: could not create leading directories of 'username@server.com:/users/home/jdquirke/rails_apps/deq/releases/20130305205259': Invalid argument

It looks to me as though my problem centers around how to tell the clone command the remote directory that I want the clone to go to.

Comment: why don't you just clone in the directory where you want the sources to be?

Comment: This is in the context of troubleshooting a Capistrano deploy:update error, so I'm trying to recreate what Capistrano is trying to do in order to figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do this with just a git command, but you can do it with an ssh command executing git on the remote server.

E.g. something like this:

```
ssh steinar@delta "git clone git@delta:private.git /tmp/git-test/private"
```

Note that I have separate users for git and for executing commands on the server. That may or may not be the case for you, depending on how git is set up on the server.